# Optimising this method c#

Tags: c#

I have a method which basically looks at a variable and if its bool IsSelected == true then it sets the value to false,  if not sets it to true.

Currently I have it written like

```
if( A.IsSelected)
{
A.IsSelected = false;
}
else
{
A.IsSelected = true;
}
```

Is it possible to write this like

```
A.IsSelected = !A.IsSelected
```

Sorry that this is a bit of a trivial question i'm just trying to cut down the ammount of code in my class and I Cant build the software to test it right now.

I know doing if (!A.IsSelected)  will invert the bool but I wasnt sure it would work in this way for setting the value.  Thanks

Comment: Why do you even ask? It's very easy for you to test that code. It should be faster than opening a web browser, go here and write a detailed question.

Comment: No Im working on a shared project on a laptop via remote desktop, Massive lag and someone else checked in an error so the project wont build! Not a great day...  Thanks for all the quick responses.

Comment: You could always create a small test-project, to see if an idea works.

Comment: That's when a local installation of the development environment, and a "scratch" project of some sort, is handy. Heck, even something like Visual C# Express will work perfectly for such things.

Comment: However, if someone checked in broken code, get them to fix it, or revert their changeset. In the meantime, if you know which changeset broke the build, just grab the one immediately prior to it and work against that, then merge your changes later.

Comment: Mac user here :(  remote desktop is the only way to go right now sadly

Comment: Install a VM to host your local dev environment. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it is possible and done all the time.

Answer (score 4):

Like @Daniel A. White points out, it's perfectly possible and very often done.

*However*, the variable must be a plain **boolean**; it cannot be **Nullable**. If it's `null`, then the expression will fail.

Answer (score 1):

You can also cut down the code if you use [ternary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) operator.

Comment: -1. The ternary operator is a wonderful invention once you've wrapped your mind around it, but how does it help cut down on the amount of code here, compared to the OP's own suggestion?

Comment: It may not be the best idea in OP's case, but it is still generally applicable in simpler if-else scenarios.